# Unable to use setState

Tags: dart, flutter

in my project im using a `ButtomNavigationBar` to switch between two pages.
The code of the switch is a standard one, using the index and setState to switch around both pages, and using an array of `Widget` to acces each page.

(Taken from the `Scaffold`)

> final `List`<`Widget`> body = [
>     `firstPage`(),
>     `secondPage`(),
>   ];
>
> body: body[_currentIndex],

and in my `secondPage()` i want to make a `ListView.Builder` with FAB that adds a tile with each tap. **To my understing i need to use setState to update the `ItemCounter` but this is not the right inhertince**
what did i do wrong and how do i correct it?

```
Widget secondPage(){
  int _itemCount = 5;
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _itemCount,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index){
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(index.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            ),
          ) ,
        );
      },
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed:(){}, //**setState need to be here**
    child: Icon(Icons.add),),
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKcu1.png)

Comment: If you want to use `setState` use a `Stateful` Widget then make the `_itemCount` a state variable so whenever you change it's value, your widget will render with the number of count your `_itemCount` variable have. [Example docs here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a stateless Widget. Your secondpage() should be a stateful Widget. The easiest way to solve this is to use a class instead of a function:

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
 int _itemCount = 5;
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _itemCount,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index){
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(index.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            ),
          ) ,
        );
      },
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed:(){
        setState((){
            _itemCount++;
        });
      },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  );
}
```

and in the List:

`final List<Widget> body = [  new firstPage(),  new secondPage(), ];`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. just needed to replace the `Widget` function with a `StafulWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

make the _itemCount variable to global variable and then use setState to increment the _itemCount value

```
int _itemCount = 5;
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView.builder(
    .....
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed:(){
      setState(() {
        _itemCount++;
      });
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),),
);;
```

}